# loadVideo() + setCurrentTime() in one onclick-Event

Tags: javascript, vimeo, vimeo-api

By clicking a button i want an embeded vimeo-player to:

- change the played video to a given ID
- jump to a given time
- play the video

At first i tried: `onclick="player.loadVideo(12345678); player.setCurrentTime(5); player.play()."`

This obviously didn't work. I already learned that the `loadVideo()`-function fires an event - so the second function has to run after this event was caught. 
Since my understanding of JavaScript is still pretty limited i would love to learn how this would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as the previous mentioned about promise. All you need is to wait for the methods complete properly. Beside writing then and catch as the old way I can recommend async await way which is more readable. you can see as following

```
const playVideo = async (id, time) => {
   try {
     await player.loadVideo(id);
     await player.setCurrentTime(time);
     await player.play();
   } catch (err) {
     console.log(err);
   } 
}
onclick="playVideo(309565369, 5)"
```

Answer (score 0):

All of the calls you are making are [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). You will want to ensure you wait for the successful return of each request before making the next. Here is an example for you

```js
var player = new Vimeo.Player('player', { id:76979871, muted: true });
player.loadVideo(309565369).then(function(id) {
    player.setCurrentTime(30).then(function(seconds) {
        player.play().then(function() {
            console.log('the video was played');
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```